# add should query in must using bool queries does not match correctly

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have a must query that includes multiple bool contains should queries..
I mean I want multiple query from the inside make OR query and from the outside make AND query.. something like this :

`(condition_1 || condition_2) && (condition_3 || condition_4) && ...`

so I handled it like below :

```
"must" => [
  [
    "terms" => [
      "status_id" => [164,163]
    ]
  ],
  [
    "term" => [
      "is_visible" => true
    ]
  ],
  [
    "bool" => [
      "should" => [
        [
          "bool" => [
            "must_not" => [
              "exists" => [
                "field" => "candidate_location_id"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "bool" => [
            "filter" => [
              "terms" => [
                "candidate_location_id" => [1]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "minimum_should_match" => 1
    ]
  ],
  [
    "bool" => [
      "should" => [
        [
          "bool" => [
            "must_not" => [
              "exists" => [
                "field" => "location_id"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "terms" => [
            "location_id" => [1,2,3,70]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

this is like this:

```
(status_id == values) AND (is_visible == true) AND ((candidate_location_id == null) OR (candidate_location_id == values)) AND ((location_id == null) OR (location_id == values))
```

my problem is I think should query is ignoring both conditions in it... I mean the query returns docs ... that the `candidate_location_id` is non of `null` or `values` that are defined in query..

also I used `minimum_should_match` as you see.. but it didn't work

if anyone has any solution to solve my problem, please share it with me.. Thank you all.

Comment: Why don't you use queryStringquery in which you can write this complicated query very easily.here is a link to it.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: Is my query wrong? I just wrote it and I think it's right..I don't know why not working @Gaurav Arya

Comment: my query is correct... the problem was because of wrong data in my elastic... it doesn't sync with my database.