# search for a field in elasticsearch that its value is NULL or any specific value

Tags: elasticsearch, search, null

I want to write a query in elasticsearch, that search in fields for null value and any specific value, 
I read this link : [null_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html)

and find out that for fields that their type is boolean or long, their defaults is null, but how can I tell elastic to search in a long field to have a value or null:

```
field == null OR field == [1,2,3,4,]
```

now when I query like this

```
'should' => [
  [
    'term' => ['field' => null]
  ],
  [
    'terms' => ['field' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]
  ]
]
```

it get me error Bad Request..

can you help me to write my query?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the existence of the field using the `exists` query.

In the query string syntax, it goes like this:

```
NOT(_exists_:field) OR field == [1,2,3,4,]
```

In the query DSL, it goes like this:

```
'should' => [
  [
    'bool' => [ 'must_not' => [ 'exists' => [ 'field' => 'field' ] ] ]
  ],
  [
    'terms' => ['field' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]
  ]
]
```

Comment: did you saw my link??
because I used a query just like yours.. and it didn't care to any of my should params... I thought it's because of my wrong query... and I'm stuck here @Val

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523312/add-should-query-in-must-using-bool-queries-does-not-match-correctly?noredirect=1#comment84047006_48523312


its a link of my last question that I described my question

Comment: make sure to also have `minimum_should_match` in your bool queries.

Comment: only once, not twice, i.e. the innermost bool but not the outer one

Comment: thanks for your quick response... its work correctly now.. the issue was the data was changed in my sql... but in my elastic index it doesn't...